# Libreoffice frequently freezes

Tags: libreoffice, freeze

I use Libreoffice to write a thesis and it frequently freezes, i. e. it turns dark for a couple of seconds, then I can continue to write. The document is 150 pages by now and only 188MB in size. I am on zesty on an Asus zenbook with 4 cores and 8 GB RAM. This only happens in libreoffice. Even Firefox which has a carnivorous appetite for resources doesn't have this behavior. I found other posts with the same problem but no solution. 
Any ideas?
Best Peter

Answer (score 3):

I did three things:

Under **Tools > Options > View** I increased memory for LibreOffice from 20 to 200 MB (have 4 GB on the machine) and memory per object from 5 to 50 MB

Under **Tools > Options > View** I turned off hardware acceleration and anti-aliasing.  Reasoning that there may be a bug where it runs algorithms that depend on acceleration and the machine did not have it.

Under **Tools > Options > Advanced** I turned off the Java virtual machine.  I could not find any Java VM on the machine so I thought it best.

For the last 24 hours under quite heavy use have not had a repeat of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of images in your document, you can try compressing it. Right Click on the image, select Compress Image option. Change the parameters to suit your needs.

If that doesn't help, try splitting the file into several small files like each chapter in different file.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the driver from **nouveau** to **nvidia-340** fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Surfing the web there are a number of people with this problem.  One of the answers on another website was to update the Nvidia graphic card with the latest drivers and doing that seemed to solve the Libre Office freezing problem for a number of people.  Since the Asus zenbook uses Nvidia maybe it will help you also.